# How to Run SSH Command with Login Shell

Tags: bash, shell, authentication, ssh, tty

I have Node.js installed by NVM on server and it doesn't work with SSH.
It shows `node: command not found` in non-login shell.

For example, this won't work

```
ssh server1 <<doc
    node -v
doc
```

This doesn't work too

```
ssh server1 <<<"bash -l; node -v"
```

The NVM init is inside .bashrc so I tried to source it but still not ok

```
ssh server1 <<doc
    source /etc/profile
    source ~/.bashrc
    node -v
doc
```

The only way to make it work is forcing ssh using TTY

```
ssh -tt server1 <<doc
    node -v
doc
```

However, the script is long and I don't wish to see the **shell printing out every command**. Even after add 'set +x' to top of script it still prints out every command.

And `-tt` will force TTY and the **ssh command doesn't stop**. Add 'exit' to the end of script is ok but still the issue of printing out command above.

How to do `ssh` without `-tt` and just as in login shell?

Comment: Doesn't `ssh server1 "bash -l -c node -v` work? Or `ssh server1 node -v`? Or `ssh server1 <PATH>/node -v"`?

Comment: even with `bash -l -c` it's still 'node command not found'

Comment: `ssh server1 <<<"bash -l -c 'node -v'"`?

Comment: Then do it specifying the full path name.

Comment: that full path can be kinda crazy, that 'node' was installed by NVM, with long long path to user dir and nested dirs inside

Comment: Perhaps the NVM init part in `.bashrc` is wrapped in a check on the tty. Can you try to extract the NVM part and write it to a new file like `.nvm_init`, and source that file?

Comment: When you want a complex set of actions done by `ssh` (sourcing files, a long path to user dir with nested dirs inside, `2>&1`, `egrep -v "parts you don't want to see|like this|or this"`) why not create a file `~/nvm_ssh_wrapper`, `chmod +x` and call this file with `ssh`?